# How to create new toolbar hairline in coreldraw

Tags: corel-draw

I have created new toolbar (Tools -> customization -> command bars -> i created new tool and drop the icons there). With the new toolbar i have add the regular tools which need. No hairline, Hairline, 0.5, 1 hairline. But in between 0.5 & 1 i want to have a 0.7 hairline that i use regular. I have to press f12 and with the mouse i have go click the hairline and with mouse i have change the figure 0.7. As it take much time. How can i have a hairline of 0.7 as default it has 0.5 & 1. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please specify the version of Coreldraw you are using

Answer (score 0):

Deselect all objects (Esc or click nothing). Now press F12. The popup dialog will ask what defaults you want to change.

[image]

Leave 'Graphic' only then in the 'Outline Pen' dialog box change the line width to 0.7. From now on, all objects will be created with the outline of 0.7.